# Php to mysql - data updating minute by minute

Tags: php, mysql

How do i update mysql table (+1) per minute with php?

Comment: What system are you on?  What have you tried?

Comment: Have you ever considered using Cron?

Comment: What does it mean `update mysql table (+1)`?

Comment: change to mysql value plus 1 . sorry for my bad english

Comment: Could you show the description of the table? What is the field you want to increment?

Answer (score 1):

PHP cannot run by itself. The only way to make PHP update a table every minute is to use a cron job that runs every minute.

If you don't have access to crons (if you're on a hosted server that doesn't allow access to crons) you can make a ad-hoc cron that will run when somebody loads a page on your website. Going down that road is certainly more complicated, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending any value in mysql query from php? If no then use a combination of simple SQL query and cron or on windows task schedular or `at` command.

write a php script to update mysql table and then google for `how to set a cron in linux`.
Probably You need to add execution environment path at the start of php file before opening `<?php` tag. I am not sure but the string goes something like this `!#path/to/php/executable`

Additionally if you are using latest MySQL then it supports `events` too, in this case you dont need to set a cron job. search for events in mysql